# printf statements not printing until Interrupt

Tags: c, printf

I've added some printf statements to some code that is run at the start of a program, but the statements aren't printing to stdout until I terminate the program with a `ctrl c` in my terminal, and they are showing up on the same line as my terminal prompt. For example the printf in the demo code below would show like this

```
[notice] Interrupt: exiting.
yabbadabbadoo/usr/local/bin 13:24:21 :
```

Why is that and how to change it? i.e. would there be somewhere in the application code that the developer has somehow set printf statements to print at exit?

```
some_function_name(){
  printf("yabbadabbadoo");

}
```

Comment: Add `fflush(stdout);`

Comment: @WeatherVane add it to where? to the program code, or to my terminal?

Comment: Add it to the program code, after the `printf` statement whose output you want to see immediately. Including a final `\n` newline often flushes the output too, but I am unsure if that is a standard feature, and there may be occasions when you do not *want* a newline.

Comment: error: linker command failed with exit code 1:  warning: implicit declaration of function 'flush' is invalid in C99

Comment: Sorry typo: `fflush`

Comment: @AlexLop the answer below seems more complete because it also provides the \n option

Comment: @Leahcim The answer in the link I posted also provides it in the accepted answer (see the first line).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *would there be somewhere in the application code that the developer has somehow set printf statements to print at exit?*

No, in general, the standard output `stdout` is [line buffered](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Buffering-Concepts.html). So unless the buffer is either full, or received a *newline*, the content is not *flushed*.

While the program is terminating, all open buffers are flushed automatically, that is why you get to see the output after terminating the program.

In your case, you need to *force* the buffer to be flushed to make the output appear on the terminal. You can either

- add a *newline* `'\n'` at the end of format string.
- use [`fflush(stdout)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fflush) after the `printf()` call

to ensure the flushing.